# NAT forwarding not working

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I tried to set up forwarding from `eth0` to `wlan0` in ubuntu:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

But it doesn't work. Pinging 10.0.0.1 (which is the default gateway on `wlan0` but not `eth0`) works on `wlan0` but not on `eth0`. When running `ping -Ieth0 10.0.0.1`, there is no output from `ping`, `tcpdump -i wlan0` shows nothing, and `tcpdump -i eth0` shows dropped ICMP packets.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what the ultimate goal is of your exercise. 
I think your problem is a routing problem.
But first I need to know more about the configuration.